# Merge Three Data Frames in R, without using SQL package

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 3 data frames in R that I am trying to merge together to run through a similar exercise to plot information on a US map by state.

Data Frame 1 = My data to analyze, which just has the FIPS US State Code.
Data Frame 2 = A lookup table essentially for Data Frame 1, which maps the state code to the name.
Data Frame 3 = Plot Information for mapping onto a state using the [all_states] function as described on [R-Bloggers](http://www.r-bloggers.com/us-state-maps-using-map_data/)[1](http://www.r-bloggers.com/us-state-maps-using-map_data/) which has the information for mapping, but it needs to be first labeled "alabama" vs. "1".

I have been playing with this for a bit and am stumbling and probably missing an obvious solution. I was trying something like this as just the first but it was not working.

> I am looking for an relatively straight forward way to bridge the "1" in my dataset to "alabama" without using the `sqldf` package nor hardcoding the FIPS table into my code. Any suggestions?

```
> withstates <- merge(FBuse,(state=States$FIPS.Code), by="state")
Error in fix.by(by.y, y) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column
```

Data Frame 1:

```
> head(FBuse$state,20)
 [1] 18  9 47 12 50 39 51 51 24 12 24 51 42 18 45 37 25 23 13 47
```

Data Frame 2:

```
> head(States)
        Name FIPS.Code USPS.Code
1    Alabama         1        AL
2     Alaska         2        AK
3    Arizona         4        AZ
4   Arkansas         5        AR
5 California         6        CA
6   Colorado         8        CO
```

Data Frame 3:

```
> head(all_states,20)
        long      lat group order  region subregion
1  -87.46201 30.38968     1     1 alabama      <NA>
2  -87.48493 30.37249     1     2 alabama      <NA>
3  -87.52503 30.37249     1     3 alabama      <NA>
4  -87.53076 30.33239     1     4 alabama      <NA>
5  -87.57087 30.32665     1     5 alabama      <NA>
6  -87.58806 30.32665     1     6 alabama      <NA>
7  -87.59379 30.30947     1     7 alabama      <NA>
8  -87.59379 30.28655     1     8 alabama      <NA>
9  -87.67400 30.27509     1     9 alabama      <NA>
10 -87.81152 30.25790     1    10 alabama      <NA>
11 -87.88026 30.24644     1    11 alabama      <NA>
12 -87.92037 30.24644     1    12 alabama      <NA>
13 -87.95475 30.24644     1    13 alabama      <NA>
14 -88.00632 30.24071     1    14 alabama      <NA>
15 -88.01778 30.25217     1    15 alabama      <NA>
16 -88.01205 30.26936     1    16 alabama      <NA>
17 -87.99486 30.27509     1    17 alabama      <NA>
18 -87.95475 30.27509     1    18 alabama      <NA>
19 -87.90318 30.28082     1    19 alabama      <NA>
20 -87.82870 30.28655     1    20 alabama      <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the column names don't match use `by.x` and `by.y`. In your case:

```
merge(FBuse, States, by.x="state", by.y = "FIPS.Code", all = TRUE)
```

The `all` argument reveals any missing rows in jour join. You can remove it
if you want "inner" join.

The step from *Alabama* to *alabama* is similar. Except you have to take care of the caps. With changing column values with `tolower` for example.

#### Using dplyr

With dplyr package you could put it like this:

```
library(dplyr)

FBuse %>%
  left_join(States, by = c("state" = "FIPS.Code")) %>%
  mutate(Name = tolower(Name)) %>%
  left_join(all_states, by = c("Name" = "region"))
```

and change from `left_join` to `inner_join` as needed.